# How to merge two responses and return it to promise?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, async-await

I am making two calls i see firstCallData prints data fine but when i do `+=` to merge response its returning me the  `Response` below added to the question , what could be better approach to achieve this task ?

main.ts

```
let data = await this.processResponse(__data.Details[0]);

    console.log("firstCallData" , data);

    data += await this.orderResponse(__data.Details[1]);

    console.log("DATA", data);
    return Promise.resolve(data);
```

Response:

```
[object Object][object Object]
```

Comment: `+` does not merge objects.  Depending on what you're actually trying to do, you might want `Object.assign()`.

Comment: thanks for the tip it worked with spread `const newItem = { ...data_0, ...data_1};`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `Object.assign()` ([MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)).

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

An example:

```
let data1 = await this.processResponse(__data.Details[0]); //let's say this promise returns {foo: 4, bar: 49}

console.log("firstCallData" , data1);

let data2 = await this.orderResponse(__data.Details[1]); //and this one returns {baz: 69, bar: 42}

data = Object.assign(data2, data1);

console.log("DATA", data);
return Promise.resolve(data);
```

It will 'merge' the objects and return this:

```
{foo: 4, bar: 49, baz: 69}
```

Note that for overlapping properties, it chooses `data1`, the source object(s) instead of the target object (`data2`).